# Namespace organization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
Root    
    - Controllers 
               - CommonController 
                    namespace Nop.Web.Controllers
                    {
                      public partial class CommonController
                      {
                        ....
                       }
                   }

    - Areas (book)
            - Controllers
                        - CommonController
                            namespace Nop.Web.Controllers
                            {
                              public partial class CommonController
                              {
                                  public ActionResult LoginBox(...)
                                 {..}
                              }
                            }
            - View
                      - Common
                              - LoginBox.cshtml
```

So now inside a layout view in area Book, how can I call the login box

> @Html.Action("LoginBox", "Customer")  => {"The controller for path '/book' was not found or does not implement IController."}

certainly because it doesn't have the exact namespace

> @Html.Action("LoginBox", "Customer", new { area = "" })

=> does get in the controller but cannot find the view because it uses the root namespace to find the location for Loginbox view which is a wrong path.

So is there anyway to still be able to keep to loginbox.cshtml in the Book area but the Common Controller can share other APIs.

Comment: Why are you using partial classes and not inheritance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use inheritance and not partial classes:

```
Root    
- Controllers 
           - CommonController 
                namespace Nop.Web.Controllers
                {
                  public class CommonController
                  {
                    ....
                   }
               }

- Areas (book)
        - Controllers
                    - CustomerController
                        namespace Nop.Web.Areas.Book.Controllers
                        {
                          public class CustomerController : CommonController
                          {
                              public ActionResult LoginBox(...)
                             {..}
                          }
                        }
        - View
                  - Customer
                          - LoginBox.cshtml
```

Then the following call should work:

```
@Html.Action("LoginBox", "Customer")
```